# xilinx vertex5 ML505-V5LX110T

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am unable to find clk and data pins of xilinx virtex5 ML505 V5LX110T. It is only mentioned in the Datasheet that P4 pin is assigned for PS2 but separate pins for clk and data are not specified. Please help for same.

Comment: Your question appears to reflect a lack of research effort. See http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards/ml505/ml505_12.1/docs/ml50x_U1_fpga.ucf. The UCF file was found via a link in the ML505/ML506/ML507 
Reference Design User Guide (User Guide 349), which was found by googling *virtex5 ML505 V5LX110T* leading to [Xilinx ML505 Evaluation Platform Documentation](http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards/ml505/docs.htm) and leads to [ML505 Reference Designs](http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards/ml505/ml505_11.1_1/reference_designs.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Such questions are usually easily answered if you look at the [schematic](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ml50x_schematics.pdf).

Your question it is unclear of which PS/2 connector you wish to use. The signals that are connected to the FPGA are called MOUSE_CLK, MOUSE_DATA, KEYBOARD_CLK, KEYBOARD_DATA (see pages 12 and 3 of schematic).

From the [UCF](http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards/ml505/ml505_12.1/docs/ml50x_U1_fpga.ucf), you can find them as well:

> NET  MOUSE_CLK            LOC="R27";   # Bank 15, Vcco=1.8V, DCI using 49.9 ohm resistors
>   NET  MOUSE_DATA           LOC="U26";   # Bank 15, Vcco=1.8V, DCI using 49.9 ohm resistors
>
> NET  KEYBOARD_CLK         LOC="T26";   # Bank 15, Vcco=1.8V, DCI using 49.9 ohm resistors
>   NET  KEYBOARD_DATA        LOC="T25";   # Bank 15, Vcco=1.8V, DCI using 49.9 ohm resistors